# git push -f only changed history of master not the files

Tags: git, github

I wanted to revert a bunch of changes in my remote master branch , so I reverted to an older commit in local and then did `git push -f` .

The history in remote master got updated but the files still have the changes from the removed commits .

Any idea what I did wrong here? And how do I ensure that even my files are reverted along with commit history?

Comment: How did you perform this revert? With what git command?

Comment: git reset <old-commit-id>;

git push -f

Comment: "The history in remote master got updated but the files still have the changes..." ; What commands are you using, and what results are you seeing, that lead you to this conclusion?  It's not clear to me what this means, because what it seems to mean at face value is not possible.

Comment: Where are you seeing that "the files still have the changes from the removed commits"? In GitHub's web UI? Or maybe you're trying to use Git as a deployment tool?

Comment: I used

 git reset &lt;oldercommitid&gt;

git push -f


The result I see was that the commit history had removed the unwanted commit but when I opened the code , I can still see the unwanted changes from the removed commits

Comment: Yes in github ui and after deployment too the code supposed to be removed is executing... Not using git as deployment tool ..using Jenkins for deployment

Answer (score -2):

Yes in github ui and after deployment too the code supposed to be removed is executing.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: Unable to delete it .. please help if u can delete the same